# Java - find tzdata version in use regardless of JRE version

Tags: java, timezone

We have a simple utility app that reads all the time zone data used in a JRE and displays it all in a simple table. We need to use an older version of the JRE (6_24) for an upcoming product release (due to other issues apparently), but we also need to include newer time zone updates in that release (that would otherwise be included in, say, 6_29). We're already packaging a private JRE that will be installed, so getting the time zone updates into that private JRE using the [TZUpdater tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) is not the issue - The issue is reading/verifying which version of the [tzdata](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) (e.g. tzdata2010o, tzdata2011k) is being read with the utility app (i.e. which version is being used in the JRE the app is running in). The app currently displays the *JRE version* in the title bar, but with the time zone updates, that's no longer sufficient to determine which *time zone data* version is in use.

I've looked into the [TimeZone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) class, but it doesn't seem to provide this information - perhaps there is a system property that holds this info? The TZUpdater tool knows which version is being used, so it must be available somewhere - I can't imagine they would analytically determine which version is in use in the update tool... Anybody know where to locate this info?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In one of my JREs, there's a file in `JRE_PATH\lib\zi` named `ZoneInfoMappings`. In the first line it displays the data you are looking for.

I'm going to search for a less hackish way, will update answer if I find something.

UPDATE:
Seems that there's no API to get this data. However, the code in the class `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile` shows how to parse it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the folder that gets replaced by TZUpdater, and I did notice (after posting the question) that ZoneInfoMappings contains that line, but Notepad++ shows some other data/characters around it in that first line that made me think it would require some hackish stuff to get to it... So hopefully there's either a better way to get to it from the JRE or somebody could post code to read that file/line...

Comment: used code here as an example to parse this out:  http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfoFile.java.html

Comment: If you are using Linux, you can do this from the command line: `strings ZoneInfoMappings | head -2`

Comment: In Java 8, you can use `ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions("UTC")`.

Comment: @Andreas Please post your comment as a separate Answer. Important, and distinct from the other Answers.

Answer (score 13):

## `ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions`

In Java 8, you can use [`ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions("UTC")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesProvider.html#getVersions-java.lang.String-):

> The exact meaning and format of the version is provider specific. The version must follow lexicographical order, thus the returned map will be order from the oldest known rules to the newest available rules. The default 'TZDB' group uses version numbering consisting of the year followed by a letter, such as '2009e' or '2012f'.

Example:

```
System.out.println(
    java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider
                  .getVersions("UTC")
                  .lastEntry()
                  .getKey()
);
```

In my Oracle Java 8u91, I get:

`2016a`

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/r8AqCw).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hackish thing that worked for me in both IBM and Oracle JREs:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "zi" + File.separator + "ZoneInfoMappings");
    if (f.exists()) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buf = new byte[11];
        try {
            fis.skip(11);
            fis.read(buf);
            System.out.print("Olson Database version is ");
            System.out.println(new String(buf));
        } finally {
            fis.close();
        }
    }       
}
```

My jdk1.6.0_29 jre says tzdata2012i, and my websphere7 JDK says tzdata2011g

You can google those to see whether your JDK is updated, and which zones have what tz changes.

Answer (score 1):

The upvoted solution works, but instead of writing and executing code, one can also ask the TZ Updater tool itself for each installed JRE:

```
<PATH to JRE bin dir>/java -jar tzupdater.jar -V
```

Sample Output:

```
tzupdater version 2.3.2-b02
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2018g
tzupdater tool would update with tzdata version: tzdata2021a
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, use

```
findstr tzdata <java-home>\lib\zi\ZoneInfoMappings
```

The following reference and link was useful for complete understanding of the tzdata in JRE.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html

To determine TZData in other platforms, please refer
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/time-zone001.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azul JDK, you can find this information here:
JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/tzdb.dat

Example (Linux):

```
$ stings tzdb.dat | grep -i "America/Sao_Paulo"
America/Sao_Paulo
```