# A day without midnight

Tags: timezone

There's at least one time zone that skips from **23:59:59** to **1:00:00** when "springing forward" for DST. Does anyone know what it is?

The following normally gets today's date, but it fails one day a year for time zones matching the above criterion.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'say DateTime->today( time_zone => $ARGV[0] )->ymd;' \
   America/New_York
2013-08-28
```

I need the time zone for testing purposes. I'm not trying to get the above code to work.

Comment: (The question may use `perl` and DateTime to demonstrate why I'm looking for this information, but the question is independent of both.)

Comment: Sure.  But different implementations will do different things if you try to work with an invalid time.  Some will error, but some will round up implicitly.  In perl, you can use the "floating" time zone to work around this.

Comment: @Matt Johnson, I already know how to get the right answer from DateTime.

Comment: A better example might be to use "now" in Brazil, then switch to floating, then truncate to get the date.  This will avoid the error you get when using "today".

Comment: @Matt Johnson, No, that wouldn't cause the error.

Comment: You may also be interested to know that Samoa (Pacific/Apia) lost an entire day (Dec 30) in 2011! [BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-16351377)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several. As of 2020-04, there are 14 such time zones in 10 countries: Paraguay, Cuba, Chile, Greenland/Denmark, Jordan, Lebanon, Syria, Palestine, Iran, and Azores/Portugal.

Before 2019-04, the list included [Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=233) using the `America/Sao_Paulo` time zone.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'say DateTime->new(
     year => 2013, month => 10, day => 20, hour => 12,
     time_zone => "America/Sao_Paulo")->truncate( to => "day" )->ymd;'
Invalid local time for date in time zone: America/Sao_Paulo
```

You can get around the problem by switching to the "floating" time zone before getting the date:

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'say DateTime->new(
     year => 2013, month => 10, day => 20, hour => 12,
     time_zone => "America/Sao_Paulo")
   ->set_time_zone("floating")
   ->truncate( to => "day" )
   ->ymd;'
2013-10-20
```

See [this documentation](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edrolsky/DateTime-1.03/lib/DateTime.pm#Making_Things_Simple).

Comment: Also, there is [Lebanon](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=34) (`Asia/Beirut`) and [Syria](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=487) (`Asia/Damascus`)

Comment: FYI: Brazil [canceled DST observance as of 2019-04](https://time.is/time_zone_news/no_dst_in_brazil_in_2019).

Comment: To produce a list of time zones with a DST cutover at midnight, see code example in [Answer by M. Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61328380/642706). As of 2020-04, there are 14 such time zones in 10 countries: Paraguay, Cuba, Chile, Greenland/Denmark, Jordan, Lebanon, Syria, Palestine, Iran, and Azores/Portugal.

Answer (score 4):

I've thrown together a small program in Java to find all zones that contain a date in 2020 where the start of the date is not midnight.  Its output lists all the time zones on my machine and version of Java matching your requirements as of 2020, as well as the date & time of the non-midnight start of day.

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ListTimeZonesWithoutMidnight {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Java vendor & version: %s %s\n", System.getProperty("java.vendor"), Runtime.version());
        System.out.printf("Zone rules versions: %s\n", ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions("UTC").keySet());
        System.out.println();

        ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().sorted().map(ZoneId::of)
                .flatMap(zoneId -> getNonMidnightStartOfDays(Year.of(2020), zoneId))
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Stream<LocalDate> getAllDates(Year year) {
        return year.atDay(1).datesUntil(year.plusYears(1).atDay(1));
    }

    private static Stream<ZonedDateTime> getNonMidnightStartOfDays(Year year, ZoneId zoneId) {
        return getAllDates(year).map(d -> d.atStartOfDay(zoneId))
                .filter(d -> !d.toLocalTime().equals(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Java vendor & version: AdoptOpenJDK 14.0.1+7
Zone rules versions: [2019c]

2020-10-04T01:00-03:00[America/Asuncion]
2020-03-08T01:00-04:00[America/Havana]
2020-09-06T01:00-03:00[America/Santiago]
2020-03-29T01:00Z[America/Scoresbysund]
2020-03-27T01:00+03:00[Asia/Amman]
2020-03-29T01:00+03:00[Asia/Beirut]
2020-03-27T01:00+03:00[Asia/Damascus]
2020-03-27T01:00+03:00[Asia/Gaza]
2020-03-27T01:00+03:00[Asia/Hebron]
2020-03-21T01:00+04:30[Asia/Tehran]
2020-03-29T01:00Z[Atlantic/Azores]
2020-09-06T01:00-03:00[Chile/Continental]
2020-03-08T01:00-04:00[Cuba]
2020-03-21T01:00+04:30[Iran]
```

Those 14 zone names are in 10 countries: Paraguay, Cuba, Chile, Greenland/Denmark, Jordan, Lebanon, Syria, Palestine, Iran, and Azores/Portugal.

Comment: I added a couple of lines of code to show the version of Java and the version of the bundled [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Your previous example output was incorrect, presumably because your JDK had an outdated tzdata. For example, Brazil [canceled DST observance as of 2019-04](https://time.is/time_zone_news/no_dst_in_brazil_in_2019). I ran your code under Java 14.0.1 with tzdata 2019c, and used its output to replace the original output shown here.

Comment: By the way, I used source code for getting *tzdata* version number from this Question: [*Java - find tzdata version in use regardless of JRE version*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7956044/642706), specifically [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775223/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque — My version of `tzdata` was "2018i".

Comment: Looks like the [Brazil zones were updated](https://tzdata-meta.timtimeonline.com/metadata/2019) in tzdata 2019b. Also, your list was missing a couple zones that appeared when I ran your code. And, thanks for that code, a very nice contribution.