# How to get last month date using Date::Calc in perl?

Tags: perl

How to get last month date using Date::Calc in perl?

For example, today is 8/2018 - I would like the function to return 7/2018.

If the date today is 1/2019 - it should return 12/2018

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1223910).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code

```
use Date::Calc qw(:all);

my ($current_year,$current_month,$current_day)=Today;

my ($result_year,$result_month,$result_day)=Add_Delta_YM($current_year,$current_month,$current_day,0,-1);
```

If you need fulll month name use below format

```
my $result_month_name=Month_to_Text($result_month);
```

Comment: It's awesome. This is i am expecting. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Date::Calc seems to make everything far more complex than it needs to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Date::Calc qw[Today Add_Delta_Days];

my @today = Today;

my ($year, $month) = Add_Delta_Days(@today, -$today[2]);

say "$month/$year";
```

I'd recommend looking at [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime;

my $today = DateTime->today;
$today->subtract(days => $today->day);
say $today->strftime('%m/%Y');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: The DateTime version is not equivalent; it uses the date at UTC+0 instead of the local date. `DateTime->today` should be `DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' )->set_time_zone('floating')->truncate( to => 'days' )`

Comment: @ikegami you can pass the time_zone to today() directly (and any other DateTime constructor). `DateTime->today(time_zone => 'local')`

Comment: @Grinnz, No, not safely, you can't. In at least three time zones around the world, that will [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18489927/589924) one day a year

Comment: @ikegami interesting. Well the time of day is not important to this problem anyway so `->now(time_zone => 'local')` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) provides a nice alternative as well:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Time::Moment;

say Time::Moment->now->minus_months(1)->strftime('%m/%Y');
```