# Sort dates using DateTime->compare()

Tags: perl

I am trying to sort an array of dates chronologically using [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use Date::Time;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%D',
    time_zone => 'America/New_York',
);
 my @dates = (
    [1, '5/18/2011'],
    [2, '6/18/2011'],
    [3, '6/18/2014'],
    [4, '6/18/2010'],
);

my @res = sort { date_sort( $a->[1], $b->[1], $strp ) } @dates;

p \@res;

sub date_sort {
    my ( $date1, $date2, $strp ) = @_;

    my $dt1 = $strp->parse_datetime($date1);
    my $dt2 = $strp->parse_datetime($date2);
    return DateTime->compare($dt1, $dt2);
}
```

**Output**:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] 1,
        [1] "5/18/2011"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] 2,
        [1] "6/18/2011"
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] 3,
        [1] "6/18/2014"
    ],
    [3] [
        [0] 4,
        [1] "6/18/2010"
    ]
]
```

**Expected output**:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] 4,
        [1] "6/18/2010"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] 1,
        [1] "5/18/2011"
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] 2,
        [1] "6/18/2011"
    ],
    [3] [
        [0] 3,
        [1] "6/18/2014"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Tip: If you're dealing with dates (not times), then use `time_zone => 'floating'`. Using the local time zone could give you [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489927/a-day-without-midnight).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%D` is equivalent to `%m/%d/%y`, where `%y` is a 2-digit year. You want to use the format`%m/%d/%Y` to support a four digit year. With `%D` (and `%m/%d/%y`), all of your input is interpreted as having the year 2020.

Answer (score 3):

[ *This is a comment rather than an answer* ]

Using DateTime is overkill here.

```
sub date_sort {
    my ( $date1, $date2 ) = @_;
    $date1 = sprintf '%3$s%1$02s%2$02s', split /\//, $date1;
    $date2 = sprintf '%3$s%1$02s%2$02s', split /\//, $date2;
    return $date1 cmp $date2;
}

my @res = sort { date_sort( $a->[1], $b->[1] ) } @dates;
```

Better yet,

```
use Sort::Key qw( ikeysort );

sub date_key {
    my ( $date ) = @_;
    return sprintf '%3$s%1$02s%2$02s', split /\//, $date;
}

my @res = ikeysort { date_key( $_->[1] ) } @dates;
```