# How to get most recently created directory using perl?

Tags: perl

Ed:- i have below directories

- 2019-05-20_16-38-21
- 2019-05-20_16-38-22
- 2019-05-20_16-38-23
- 2019-05-20_16-38-24

i need to pick 2019-05-20_16-38-24 this directory as variable using perl

Is it possible ?

Comment: See also [Sort dates using DateTime->compare()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55908645/2173773)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative to @choroba's answer if your directories are not named consistently.  It uses [File::stat](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::stat) (which comes standard with Perl) and a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to sort on creation date of the directories:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

my $parent = '.';    # parent directory you're searching

# Schwartzian Transform to sort directories by their creation time
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform
my @dirs =
  map { $_->[0] }                      # 3. extract the directory names from the sorted list
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }         # 2. sort the arrays on creation time
  map { [ $_ => stat( $_ )->ctime ] }  # 1. get the creation time for each directory
                                       #    and store it with the directory name in an array
  glob( "$parent/*/" );                # 0. get the directories in the parent dir

my $most_recent = $dirs[-1];           # the last one is the most recent
```

Answer (score 1):

For timestamps in the given format, normal string comparison works, so you can use `maxstr` from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ maxstr };

my @dirs = qw(
    2019-05-20_16-38-21
    2019-05-20_16-38-22
    2019-05-20_16-38-23
    2019-05-20_16-38-24
);

my $most_recent = maxstr(@dirs);
```

Comment: I don't understand. Just populate `my @dirs = glob '*/';` instead of hardcoding the directories.