# How do I get yesterday's date in perl?

Tags: perl, date

Currently i take today date using below.I need to get yesterday date using this.. how can i get that ?

```
my $today = `date "+%Y-%m-%d"`;
```

Comment: This asks about "yesterday" but the example uses HMS ... do you indeed need time as well, or just date?

Comment: actually @Heyddo answer worked for me. however i use above to create directories using timestamps. But i get it with \n. ed :-  2019-05-14\n but i do not pass any enter.. any idea what causes for this ?

Comment: "_But i get it with \n._" -- the backticks return that; you need to `chomp`

Comment: actually i want today and yesterday both. so i take the today using above and now i can take yesterday using today  as @Heyddo 's answer

Comment: What output do you want for times that don't exist (For example, 1 day before 2019-03-10T02:30:00 in New York)?

Comment: @zdim ahh yes chomp i've missed thanks

Comment: "_now i can take yesterday using today_"  -- well, no, you can't do any date-time arithmetic using the system `date` command and its return.  You have to run the whole thing for every other day you want.  This is one of reasons why I recommend to use a module, in which case you _can_ manipulate dates as you wish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want yesterday's date:

```
use DateTime qw( );

my $yday_date =
   DateTime
      ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
      ->set_time_zone('floating')
      ->truncate( to => 'day' )
      ->subtract( days => 1 )
      ->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

For example, in New York on 2019-05-14 at 01:00:00, it would have returned 2019-05-13.

For example, in New York on 2019-11-04 at 00:00:00, it would have returned 2019-11-03.

Note that `->now( time_zone => 'local' )->set_time_zone('floating')->truncate( to => 'day' )` is used instead of `->today( time_zone => 'local' )` to avoid [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18489927/589924).

---

If you want the time a day earlier:

```
use DateTime qw( );

my $yday_datetime =
   DateTime
      ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
      ->subtract( days => 1 )
      ->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

For example, in New York on 2019-05-14 at 01:00:00, it would have returned 2019-05-13 01:00:00.

For example, in New York on 2019-03-10 at 12:00:00, it would have returned 2019-03-09 12:00:00.

For example, in New York on 2019-03-11 at 02:30:00, it would have resulted in an error. 2019-03-10 02:30:00 didn't exist because of the switch to Daylight Saving Time.

---

If you want the time 24 hours earlier:

```
use DateTime qw( );

my $yday_datetime =
   DateTime
      ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
      ->subtract( hours => 24 )
      ->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

For example, in New York on 2019-05-14 at 01:00:00, it would have returned 2019-05-13 01:00:00.

For example, in New York on 2019-03-10 at 12:00:00, it would have returned 2019-03-09 11:00:00.

For example, in New York on 2019-03-11 at 02:30:00, it would have returned 2019-03-10 01:30:00.

Comment: I have to use `day` instead of `days` in truncate to  prevent the following exception: `Validation failed for type named TruncationLevel declared in package DateTime::Types (C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/DateTime/Types.pm) at line 135 in sub named (eval) with value "days"`

Comment: @nck Indeed. Fixed

Answer (score 10):

Using [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime;

my $today = DateTime->today(time_zone => 'local');

my $yesterday = $today->clone->add(days => -1);

say $yesterday->ymd;  #--> 2019-05-13
```

or directly

```
my $yesterday = DateTime->today(time_zone => 'local')->add(days => -1);
```

Now these are objects with which you can do practically anything date-time related.

To extract a string in the question's format use `$yesterday->ymd` since [ymd](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Eymd(-$optional_separator-),-$dt-%3Emdy(...),-$dt-%3Edmy(...))'s default format is `%Y-%m-%d`. Practically arbitrary formats can be obtained using [strftime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Estrftime(-$format,-...-)) method.

---

There is no reason to reach for system facilities for a job like this. More to the point, the module is incomparably more sophisticated and rounded, for all kinds of curious cases and needs.

An example: At some date-times, as Daylight Saving Time kicks in, certain time periods just *don't exist*. The docs [offer an example](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Invalid-Local-Times) of 2003-04-06, when 01:59:59 "jumps" to 03:00:00 and that hour is gone.  The  module handles attempts to use such (non-existing times) correctly, by throwing errors.

And if you need to do any work with dates then using system's `date` isn't even an option since you get back merely a string, which you'd have to parse by hand for any further use.

---

It has been added that in fact the time is wanted as well, not only the date.  Then, for example

```
my $today = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');

say $today->strftime("%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S");         #--> 20190522_22.44.23

my $yesterday = $today->clone->add(days => -1);

say $yesterday->strftime("%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S");     #--> 20190521_22.44.23
```

where method [now](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#DateTime-%3Enow(-...-)) "keeps" the (local) time, along with the date (`today` is `truncate`-ed `now`).

Comment: Note: This (rightfully) fails for times that don't exist (1 day before 2019-03-10T02:30 in New York). If you just want the date (not the time), then you could use `->set_time_zone('floating')` to stop it from failing.

Comment: @zdim  just I'm curious. Is it possible to run one time and get days using that ? Eg:- using datetime i take today (YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS) using today can i take yesterday or X days before day  without running each time ?

Comment: @Debugger That would be the second way in the answer ("_or directly_"), if I get what you want?  Like, `my $d_N_back = DateTime->today(time_zone=>"local")->add(days=>-$N);`  (where `$N` has the number).  Now this is an object you can work with. If you'd rather get a ready string back, continue that chain: `my $str = DateTime->[as above]->ymd;`.  Or, for more specific formats, `->strftime(...)`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Debugger  As I read again i don't understand "_without running each time_" ...?  Once you have one of them you can get any other day from it in one statement -- is that what you want with "_using today can i take yesterday or X days before_"? Like `$N_back = $today->clone->add(days=>-$N);`. Here `clone` makes another object from `$today` so you keep `$today` and get a new object, for `$N` days before today.  Or, to get a string, `$N_back_str = $today->clone->add(days=>-$N)->ymd;`

Comment: @zdim here is the thing.I'm creating perl script and i need to create directories using timestamps.before i went with Y-M-D but now i plan to go with Y-M-D-H-M-S in case if the script runs few times in a day. your above one gives 2019-05-23T00:00:00 this out put.thanks for your help.

Comment: @Debugger Alright, thank you -- added time to the answer, for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using DateTime (as described in ikegami's answer). But if you don't want to install a CPAN module, this method uses only features available in the standard Perl installation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Local;
use POSIX 'strftime';

# Get the current date/time
my ($sec, $min, $hr, $day, $mon, $yr) = localtime;

# Get the epoch seconds for midday today
# (we use midday to eliminate potential problems
# when entering or leaving daylight savings time)
my $midday = timelocal(0, 0, 12, $day, $mon, $yr);

# Subtract a day's worth of seconds from the epoch
my $midday_yesterday = $midday - (24 * 60 * 60);

# Convert that epoch value to a string date using
# localtime() and POSIX::strftime().
my $yesterday = strftime('%Y%m%d', localtime($midday_yesterday));

say $yesterday;
```

Answer (score 3):

With [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment), for just yesterday's date:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Moment;
my $yesterday = Time::Moment->now->minus_days(1)->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

Time::Moment works in instants and offsets, not time zones, so if you want the exact date and time of "one day ago" in your local time zone as in the DateTime examples, you can use [Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Moment;
use Role::Tiny ();
my $class = Role::Tiny->create_class_with_roles('Time::Moment', 'Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone');
my $yesterday = $class->now->minus_days(1)->with_system_offset_same_local; # 1 day ago
my $yesterday = $class->now->minus_days(1)->with_system_offset_same_instant; # 24 hours ago
```

And the same caveats apply if the current time does not exist in the previous day in the local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $yesterday = `date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`;
```

Comment: thanks for the help, so if i need day before yesterday i can add -2d ?

Comment: date -d -2days +%Y%m%d

Comment: This does not always work. It will sometimes give a time that's off by one hour. (e.g. It gives `20190309-110000` for `20190310-120000` in New York.)

Comment: Using an external program for something this simple isn't a good idea. It reduces the portability of your code and makes it slower unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Using the backtick string has some quirks.... I generally disklike that operator.

Let me recommand the use of `localtime()` function provided by `Time::Piece` module (there is a bulitin `localtime()` function, but the one from `Time::Piece` is awesomer :)

```
use Time::Piece;

my ($t, $today, $yesterday);

$t = localtime();
$today = sprintf('%04d/%02d/%02d', $t->year, $t->mon, $t->mday);

$t = localtime(time() - 86400);
$yesterday = sprintf('%04d/%02d/%02d', $t->year, $t->mon, $t->mday);
```

Comment: This does not always work. It will sometimes give today's date, and it will sometimes give the date two days ago. Time::Piece is a bad module because it makes these kinds of error incredibly easy to make.

Comment: @ikegami I'd argue that the math is wrong with my example code rather Time::Piece. :-) IMHO Time::Piece is as good as how it is documented. I probably shouldn't be using Time-math to do Date calculation...

Comment: Re "*I'd argue that the math is wrong with my example code*", Me too. It's definitely a misuse of the module. (You want `localtime(time()) - 86400` or just `localtime() - 86400` instead of `localtime(time() - 86400)`) But the fact that the module encourages this type of mistake is a problem with the module.