# Perl get date before to ten days of particular date

Tags: perl, date

I need to get a date which is 10 days before to the inputted date.

Here is my script - ( Ref. taken from Dave's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56125332/6124824) )

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $DATE = $ARGV[0];
( $DATE =~ /(....)(..)(..)/ );

my ($day, $mon, $yr) = ( $3, $2, $1 );

my $midday = timelocal(0, 0, 12, $day, $mon, $yr); 

my $midday_before = $midday - (10 * 24 * 60 * 60);

my $required_date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', localtime($midday_before));

print "10 days to before ".$yr."-".$mon."-".$day." is : $required_date\n";
```

But my output looks like this, which I am confused:

```
$ perl get_date.pl 20200527
10 days to before 2020-05-27 is : 2020-06-17
```

I am expecting `2020-05-17`. But its giving me `2020-06-17` which is 20 days ahead of my inputted date.

I don't want to use `DateTime` to achieve this. Since there is a permission issue in installing the modules.

Comment: Re "*Since there is a permission issue in installing the modules*", No special permissions are needed to install module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for [Time::Local](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) a little more carefully. It includes this:

> It is worth drawing particular attention to the expected ranges for
>   the values provided. The value for the day of the month is the actual
>   day (i.e. 1..31), while the month is the number of months since
>   January (0..11). This is consistent with the values returned from
>   `localtime()` and `gmtime()`.

In the code that you copied, I used `localtime()` to get the month (and the other parts of the date) and that gave me an integer between 0 and 11. In your code, you parse the value out of your input string and that gives you a number between 1 and 12. You therefore need to subtract 1 from your month before passing it to `timelocal()`.

This is one of the reasons why better date/time tools like [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) and [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) were written. Please don't ignore them.

**Update:** Time::Piece version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $today = Time::Piece->strptime($ARGV[0], '%Y%m%d');
my $then = $today - (10 * ONE_DAY);

my $fmt = '%Y-%m-%d';

print '10 days to before ', $today->strftime($fmt),
      ' is : ', $then->strftime($fmt), "\n";
```

Comment: thanks Dave for the response. Is there any way which I can do this using modules which comes with standard Perl installation. Like you mentioned of `POSIX` & `Time::Local`.

Comment: vkk05: If you're using a perl newer than 5.10 (~2007), `Time::Piece` should be included in core perl.

Comment: @vkk05: I'm confused. I've explained exactly how to fix your existing code so it works. But as Jim says, you should have Time::Piece installed already.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My Perl version is `This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi` and when I execute above code it says `Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ..`

Comment: @vkk05, You have a broken/partial install (since Time::Piece is part of Perl 5.10), and that's an very old version of Perl.

Comment: @vkk05: You're almost certainly running up again [this problem](https://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/). But it doesn't matter, if you follow the instructions in my answer, you can do this without Time::Piece.

Comment: thanks Dave & @ikegami for clarifying it. Really appreciate the help :)