# strftime not giving year of struct tm

Tags: c, date, strftime

I have this function that gets the day before an input date:

```
Date dateDayBefore(char* inputDate)
{
     struct tm dayBefore = { 0 };

     char** fields = split(inputDate, 3, "/");

     dayBefore.tm_mday = atoi(fields[0]);
     dayBefore.tm_mon = atoi(fields[1]) - 1;
     dayBefore.tm_year = atoi(fields[2]) - 1900;

     dayBefore.tm_mday--;
     mktime(&dayBefore);

     char yesterday[10];
     strftime(yesterday, sizeof(yesterday), "%d/%m/%Y", &dayBefore);

     Date yesterdayDate = dateCreate(yesterday);
     yesterdayDate.year += 1900;
     return yesterdayDate;
}
```

Assume all other functions used are correct(such as split and dateCreate), they're used in other places where everything is as expected.

`struct dayBefore` will contain the year but `string yesterday` will not contemplate it after `strftime`

For:
inputDate = 15/06/2020

expected result: 14/06/2020

actual result: 14/06/1900

Some screenshots of debugging:

[image][image]

Comment: What is `dateCreate`? Is your problem related to the fact that `yesterday` is local to the function? Please provide a minimal, *runnable* demonstration of the problem. (See [mcve])

Comment: No, the problem is inside the scope. dateCreate receives a string and returns a struct with integers as day, month, year. All that working as expected @ikegami

Comment: Please provide a minimal, *runnable* demonstration of the problem, as required. (See [mcve])

Comment: Use `strptime` and don't do your own date calculations. Calendars are insanely weird.
Parse the time into a `struct tm`, set hours, minutes and seconds to `0`. Create a `time_t` using `mktime`, subtract a few minutes, convert back to `struct tm`.

Comment: `char yesterday[10];` is not big enough. You forgot to account for the NUL.

Comment: @Cheetah, I'm not convinved that will work either. `mktime` takes a local time, and not all days have a 00:00:00 in all time zones. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18489927/589924)) If you set the TZ to UTC first, that would work.

Comment: @ikegami damn what a noob... thank you! if you want to post an answer I'll accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to store a 10-character string (`14/06/2020`) into a 10-character array, which leaves no space for the NULL.

Replace

```
char yesterday[10];
```

with

```
char yesterday[11];
```

---

There appears to be problems with how you are working with dates, but I can't address those right now.

---

Your question includes a lot of irrelevant details. You problem can be demonstrate using the following:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   char* fields[] = { "15", "06", "2020" };

   dayBefore.tm_mday = atoi(fields[0]);
   dayBefore.tm_mon = atoi(fields[1]) - 1;
   dayBefore.tm_year = atoi(fields[2]) - 1900;

   dayBefore.tm_mday--;
   mktime(&dayBefore);

   char yesterday[10];
   strftime(yesterday, sizeof(yesterday), "%d/%m/%Y", &dayBefore);
   printf("%s\n", yesterday);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, solution worked and I'll be more careful and precise demonstrating a question in the future!