# Calculate next business date by adding hours to a date now in perl

Tags: date, perl, datetime, time

I want to add to a date now, x hours and processing this dependant of businness calendar.
I don't know how to explain otherwise so an example will be more practical.

My sample business calendar is:

- Start time 9 a.m.
- End time 6 p.m.
- as well as various public holidays and weekends

I wish that :

- date now : 18-07-2022 4:30 p.m.
- to which I add 5 hours
- I have the following result : 19-07-2022 12:30 p.m.

Of course in the case where a public holiday would be in the middle, we would skip it (weekend included).
If I take my previous example but for the weekend it would be:

- start date: 15-07-2022 4:30 p.m.
- add 5 hours
- end date : 18-07-2022 12:30 p.m.

I've already use a param business calandars as following :

```
my %sansSLA = (
          1 => { Name  => 'Monday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          2 => { Name  => 'Tuesday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          3 => { Name  => 'Wednesday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          4 => { Name  => 'Thursday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          5 => { Name  => 'Friday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          6 => { Name  => 'Saturday',
                 Start => undef,
                 End   => undef},
          0 => { Name  => 'Sunday',
                 Start => undef,
                 End   => undef},
          holidays => [qw(01-01 05-01 05-08 07-14 08-15 11-11 12-25 2022-05-18 2022-05-26 2023-0410 2023-04-10 2023-05-18 2024-04-01 2024-05-09 2025-04-21 2025-05-29 2026-04-06 2026-05-14 2027-03-29 2027-05-06 2028-04-17 2028-05-25 2029-04-02 2029-05-10 2030-04-22 2030-05-30)],
   );
```

or :

```
my %sla8_18 = (
          1 => { Name  => 'Monday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          2 => { Name  => 'Tuesday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          3 => { Name  => 'Wednesday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          4 => { Name  => 'Thursday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          5 => { Name  => 'Friday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          6 => { Name  => 'Saturday',
                 Start => '8:00',
                 End   => '18:00'},
          0 => { Name  => 'Sunday',
                 Start => undef,
                 End   => undef},
          holidays => [qw(01-01 05-01 05-08 07-14 08-15 11-11 12-25 2022-05-18 2022-05-26 2023-0410 2023-04-10 2023-05-18 2024-04-01 2024-05-09 2025-04-21 2025-05-29 2026-04-06 2026-05-14 2027-03-29 2027-05-06 2028-04-17 2028-05-25 2029-04-02 2029-05-10 2030-04-22 2030-05-30)],
   );
```

and

```
my %slaMax = (
          1 => { Name  => 'Monday',
                 Start => '00:00',
                 End   => '23:59'},
          2 => { Name  => 'Tuesday',
                 Start => '00:00',
                 End   => '23:59'},
          3 => { Name  => 'Wednesday',
                 Start => '00:00',
                 End   => '23:59'},
          4 => { Name  => 'Thursday',
                 Start => '00:00',
                 End   => '23:59'},
          5 => { Name  => 'Friday',
                 Start => '00:00',
                 End   => '23:59'},
          6 => { Name  => 'Saturday',
                 Start => '00:00',
                 End   => '23:59'},
          0 => { Name  => 'Sunday',
                 Start => '00:00',
                 End   => '23:59'},
          #holidays => [qw(01-01 05-01 05-08 07-14 08-15 11-11 12-25 2022-05-18 2022-05-26 2023-0410 2023-04-10 2023-05-18 2024-04-01 2024-05-09 2025-04-21 2025-05-29 2026-04-06 2026-05-14 2027-03-29 2027-05-06 2028-04-17 2028-05-25 2029-04-02 2029-05-10 2030-04-22 2030-05-30)],
   );
```

thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: I would probably use https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime and wrap it somehow. You will have to implement some of the business logic yourself, such as checking that your times are within the boundaries, an calculating offsets to apply to arguments when you add time.

Comment: Their is no fattest solution than wrap DateTime ? I wasn't think that what i want to do is as much specific and that nobody have already develop or integrated a solution in a library. 
Thanks for your help. I'll wait for other respons just in case. 
Have a good day.

Comment: There are various date and time libraries. DateTime is not that heavy, but it depends. If you are using it in CGI it's borderline. If it's in a script that you use as an end-user, it doesn't really matter. For a PSGI based application, it's totally fine. Date::Manip has more special functionality. I haven't used it in a while, but i have used it to do next business day and things like that. Just not as specific as you need it. It is a very heavy module, that I really wouldn't want to load unless there is no other way. Much bigger than DateTime. Time::Piece is simple, and comes in core Perl.

Comment: What would be really cool is a generic wrapper around DateTime, some kind of subclass that you can tell what the constraints of your day are, and it just works, so you could do something like (and that is just a hypothetical interface I made up) `my $tomorrow = DateTime::CustomWorkdays->now->add( hours => 5 )->iso8601` and it would produce your `2022-07-18T12:30:00` when now is 4:30pm the day before.

Comment: ok, I understand the point of view and what I have to do in the idea.
In fact I want to do a personalized action following an event received in the BestPractical Request Tracker application.
I have already calculated the effective processing time and the time remaining before overrun and I would also like to add the maximum end date of the authorized processing according to the existing calendar.
What do you think would be best to integrate in this case ?

Comment: Well if it's for RT, you already have DateTime anyway (https://github.com/bestpractical/rt/blob/stable/etc/cpanfile#L21). I'm not familiar with their code base though.

Answer (score 0):

Let us code this through.

```
sub add_time {
    my $time = shift; #Assuming timestamp in seconds
    my $add = shift;  #assuming seconds

    while ( $add > 0 ) {
        my $day = get_day_record($time);
        my $time_in_day_available = time_in_day ($time, $day);
        if ($add > $time_in_day_available) {
            $add = $add - $time_in_day_available;
            $time = get_timestamp_of_next_day($time);
        } else {
            $time = start_time_of_day ($time, $day) + $add;
            $add = 0;
        }
    }
    return $time;
}
```

The rest is also easy. (Check-for-holidays needs to be done)

```
sub get_day_record {
    my $time = shift;
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
                                                localtime($time);

    if (check_for_holidays($time)) {
          return { Name  => 'holiday',
                 Start => undef,
                 End   => undef}
    } else {
        return $sansSLA{$wday};
    }
}

sub check_for_holidays {
    return ;
}


sub time_in_day {
    my $time = shift ;
    my $day = shift;
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
                                                localtime($time);

    return 0
        unless $day->{Start};

    my ($end_hour, $end_min) = split(':', $day->{End});
    my $end_work_time = timelocal(0,$end_min,$end_hour,$mday,$mon,$year);

    return 0
        if $end_work_time < $time;

    my $start_work_time = start_time_of_day ($time, $day);

    return $end_work_time - $start_work_time;
}

sub start_time_of_day {
    my $time = shift ;
    my $day = shift;
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
                                                localtime($time);


    my ($start_hour, $start_min) = split(':', $day->{Start});
    my $start_work_time = timelocal(0,$start_min,$start_hour,$mday,$mon,$year);

    return $time 
        if $start_work_time < $time;

    return $start_work_time;
}

sub get_timestamp_of_next_day {
    my $time = shift;
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
                                                localtime($time);
    return timelocal_nocheck(0,0,0,$mday+1,$mon,$year);
}
```

And the whole thing in a single script to test this (including the use of the necessary Time::Local)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local qw(timelocal timelocal_nocheck);
my %sansSLA = (
    1 => { Name  => 'Monday',
            Start => '8:00',
            End   => '18:00'},
    2 => { Name  => 'Tuesday',
            Start => '8:00',
            End   => '18:00'},
    3 => { Name  => 'Wednesday',
            Start => '8:00',
            End   => '18:00'},
    4 => { Name  => 'Thursday',
            Start => '8:00',
            End   => '18:00'},
    5 => { Name  => 'Friday',
            Start => '8:00',
            End   => '18:00'},
    6 => { Name  => 'Saturday',
            Start => undef,
            End   => undef},
    0 => { Name  => 'Sunday',
            Start => undef,
            End   => undef},
    holidays => [qw(01-01 05-01 05-08 07-14 08-15 11-11 12-25 2022-05-18 2022-05-26 2023-0410 2023-04-10 2023-05-18 2024-04-01 2024-05-09 2025-04-21 2025-05-29 2026-04-06 2026-05-14 2027-03-29 2027-05-06 2028-04-17 2028-05-25 2029-04-02 2029-05-10 2030-04-22 2030-05-30)],
);

my $start = timelocal (0,0,0,18,06,122); # this is the 18 07 2022

print scalar localtime(add_time($start, 52*60*60));
```

Comment: Passing [illegal values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18489927/589924) to `timelocal_nocheck` (as this code can do) sometimes leads to weird results.

Comment: @ikegami I am not convinced this issue can cause any problems here. Anyway, not using the timelocal_nocheck is easy. In my eyes though it's better to use a library function than write the code processing DST, Leap Seconds and so on by yourself.

Comment: Re "*In my eyes though it's better to use a library function than write the code processing DST, Leap Seconds and so on by yourself.*", Why do you think I said otherwise!?!

Comment: (I'm not the one that downvoted. I too think this will work even with the illegal values. But I did encounter a case where it didn't, and the author refused to apply a trivial fix.)

Comment: (Linux doesn't have have leap seconds in its epoch time. As such, the same is true for Windows, and probably MacOS.)

Comment: Sorry I thought you suggested that timelocal_nocheck shouldn't been used in this context.

Comment: `timelocal_nocheck` is not the only library. If you can't find a way to do it with `timelocal_nocheck`, it doesn't mean you can't use *any* library. DateTime has [DateTimeX::Start](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTimeX::Start), for example.