# How to get date of two month old date from current date

Tags: datetime, perl

I am trying to pull data (some transaction related data) from DB. To pull the data, I am passing start date and end date as an argument to the query.

Here I need to pull the data of last 2 months. i.e., Start time would be Jun 01, 2022 and End time would be Aug 01, 2022.

Below is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use Date::Format;
use Date::Parse;

my $nowdate = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');
my ($month, $year) = ($nowdate->month, $nowdate->year);

my $date = DateTime->new(
                year => $year,
                month => $month,
                day => 1,
        );
my $end_time = str2time($date);
print "END:$end_time\n";
print time2str("%d-%m-%Y %T", $end_time)."\n"; #printing just to see in human readable format

my $start_time = $date->clone;
$start_time->add( months => 1 )->subtract( days => 92 );
$start_time = str2time($start_time);
print "START:$start_time\n";
print time2str("%d-%m-%Y %T", $start_time)."\n"; #printing just to see in human readable format
```

I have two issues over here:

1. I am using `DateTime` object two times to get end time. Can it be done in one shot?
2. `$start_time->add( months => 1 )->subtract( days => 92 );` In this line of code, I have to explicitly mention subtract `92` days, which wouldn't be right always. Since some months have 30 days or 31 days or even 29 days. How can I get 2 month's beginning day date?

Another example: Lets assume if we are in September 2022, then Start time and End time would be Jul 01, 2022 and Sep 01, 2022 respectively.

Note: Perl version is 5.16.3

It would be good If I can do it with Core modules which comes with 5.16.3

Comment: Isn't `str2time($date)` just an expensive way to do `$date->epoch`?

Comment: "It would be good If I can do it with Core modules which comes with 5.16.3" so, even though you use DateTime in the example, you don't want an answer using DateTime?

Comment: That `$date` is built directly from `nowdate`, correct?  Why not `my $date = $nowdate->clone;` then, without having to first extract pieces.   (Can chain further methods like `truncate` etc)

Comment: @briandfoy Sorry for the confusion. Our environment supports ‘DateTime’.

Comment: @ikegami Not sure. Let me try it.

Comment: @zdim that makes sense to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it by using `truncate(to => 'month')` to get to the first in the current month:

```perl
my $end = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local')
                  ->truncate(to => 'month');
```

This may however fail on [a day without a midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18489927/589924) so this may be an option:

```perl
my $end = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local')
                  ->set_time_zone('floating')
                  ->truncate(to => 'month');
```

Then `subtract` the number of months to get the start date:

```perl
my $start = $end->clone->subtract( months => 2 );
```

Then:

```perl
my $start_time = str2time($start);
my $end_time = str2time($end);

print "START:$start_time\n";
print time2str("%d-%m-%Y %T", $start_time)."\n";

print "END:$end_time\n";
print time2str("%d-%m-%Y %T", $end_time)."\n";
```

Possible output:

```
START:1654034400
01-06-2022 00:00:00
END:1659304800
01-08-2022 00:00:00
```

Comment: @ikegami So, `my $start_time = $start->epoch;` would be cleaner - but could produce the wrong result if the floating thingy kicks in?

Comment: With `->set_time_zone('floating')`, `->epoch` will return `2022-01-06T00:00:00Z`, not `2022-01-06T00:00:00` local.

Comment: @ikegami In what scenario Ted's code will not pass? I didn't understand.