# How get utc datetime according specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, dayjs

All records in a database are stored in UTC:

```
createdAt: 2022-11-28T23:58:29.670Z
createdAt: 2022-11-29T00:13:23.213Z
createdAt: 2022-11-29T05:11:22.113Z
```

I need to find records by data range i.e from 2022-11-29 to 2022-11-29 (all records on that day).

These dates were converted from 'America/Santo_Domingo' timezone.

For the first step, I need to convert '2022-11-29' to UTC time but with the timezone offset.

```
const UTC = dayjs(date + 'T00:00:00Z'); // 2022-11-29T00:00:00.000Z,
```

And I have to add offset because I need a record for 2022-11-29 (but in -4 timezone). So I should get `2022-11-29T04:00:00.000Z`

```
const timeWithTimezone = UTC.tz(tz); // 2022-11-28T18:00:00.000Z - I expected 2022-11-28T20:00:00.000Z
```

And next step adds offset to UTC:

```
    const UTCwithOffset = UTC.utcOffset(timeWithTimezone.utcOffset()*-1); 
// 2022-11-29T02:00:00.000Z with some info  '$x': { '$localOffset': -120 }
```

I expected to get 2022-11-29T04:00:00.000Z which should be the date from. So I lose 2h somewhere.

Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong, so you're converting in the opposite direction.  You should instead do the following:

- Convert the inclusive date range to a half-open date-time range using the start time for each day.
  `[2022-11-29, 2022-11-29]` becomes:
  `[2022-11-29T00:00:00.000, 2022-11-30T00:00:00.000)` (note +1 day on end)
- Use the time zone to determine the offset that applies to each part, and expand the range to include the offset.
  For `America/Santo_Domingo`,
  `[2022-11-29T00:00:00.000-04:00, 2022-11-30T00:00:00.000-04:00)`
- Then convert each part to UTC:
  `[2022-11-29T04:00:00.000Z, 2022-11-30T04:00:00.000Z)`
- Compare to your database with `>=` for the start and `<` for the end.

Caveats:

- Many time zones have transitions for DST or for changes in standard time.
  If your range crosses a transition, the start and ending offsets may not be the same.  Thus, don't try to set the offset manually.  Use the time zone conversion functions of your library instead.
- Some time zones have transitions right at the stroke of midnight.  In the case of a forward transition, that could mean that `00:00` is not a valid local time on that day, but rather the day starts at `01:00`. ([See example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489927/a-day-without-midnight))  Some datetime libraries will handle this for you automatically, some will not and thus you could get incorrect results for these edge cases.  Test to find out.

I'll not provide a direct JavaScript implementation.  I'll leave that to others - or you can probably find parts of this answered already.  I will say, don't choose Moment due to its [status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).  For day.js, be sure to read about the [timezone plugin](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone).  Personally, I would choose [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/), the successor to Moment.

Comment: yes, you are right. it was what I try to do.

Comment: Sure, but in your first step you're converting to midnight UTC rather than midnight local time.  Then the middle step looks right, but the last step looks quite wrong and I'm not sure what it's trying to achieve.