# Get the current version number of `tzdata`

Tags: java, database, timezone, version, tzdata

Oracle provides the TZUpdater tool to manually update the [version of the `tzdata`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) time zone data bundled with the JVM.

How to programmatically determine the version number of the time zone data currently installed in a JVM?

I want to compare that to the current release stated on the official [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority) page, [*Time Zone Database*](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`ZoneRulesProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesProvider.html) class.

```
System.out.println(java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions("UTC").keySet());
```

For me, using 1.8.0_91, it prints `[2016a]`.

Comment: what about for JRE < 1.8 ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat See this one: [Java - find tzdata version in use regardless of JRE version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7956044/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 21, the `tzdata` version can be retrieved from the `java` command line program using the `-XshowSettings` launcher option.  The settings are under the "Locale" category, so both `-XshowSettings:locale` or `-XshowSettings:all` will display it.

**Input:**

```shell
java -XshowSettings:locale
```

**Output:**

```
Locale settings:
    default locale = English (United States)
    default display locale = English (United States)
    default format locale = English (United States)
    tzdata version = 2023c
    available locales = , af, af_NA, af_ZA, af_ZA_#Latn, agq, agq_CM, agq_CM_#Latn, 
        ak, ak_GH, ak_GH_#Latn, am, am_ET, am_ET_#Ethi, ann, ann_NG, 
[...]
```