# Change timeZone offset for ZoneId

Tags: java, spring, timezone

I am initializing TimeZone like in the next code, for [Almaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almaty) Kazakhstan [time zone](https://time.is/Almaty):

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Almaty");
```

But now it has offset:

```
21600000
```

I just wrote:

```
System.out.println("TZ : " + timeZone);
```

And I got next:

```
TZ : sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Almaty",offset=21600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=53,lastRule=null]
```

Now, I want to write some rule/config in Spring Boot so that, it always must return offset as 18000000 when I will init it through the ZoneId like this:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Almaty")
```

Please, help, how to do it

Comment: All superseded. You should be `java.time.zone` and `java.time`

Comment: The question invites people to do as you request on a technical level, but not review whether this is the right solution for the problem. Could you describe more the nature of your problem (I guess its [Kazakhstan spanning 4 geographical timezones with the standard time being 5 hour offset (`18000000ms`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Kazakhstan) but geographically and in Java's `sun.util.calendar` package 6 hour offset (`21600000ms`) is being used?

Comment: Since the time zone for Kazakhstan changed on the first of March you will probably need to use the TZUpdater explicitly and use the correct packages that I have shown above

Comment: Kazakhstan's time is a very difficult matter, telling from [those 275 lines in the OpenJDK 18 on how it evolved and is regulated](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk18/blob/0f2113cee79b9645105b4753c7d7eacb83b872c2/make/data/tzdata/asia#L2303-L2578). [Same in JDK11 btw](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/make/data/tzdata/asia#L1640-L1914) and probably most others.

Comment: @lchristmann - I think it might have recently got a lot simpler (see below)

Comment: @g00se clean solution, good job figuring that out! This is defeinitely the preferred way over dirty manipulation of timezone offsets at runtime with Java code.

Comment: FYI… `TimeZone` is now legacy, having been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, built into Java 8+. Specifically replaced by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) & `ZoneOffset`.

Comment: @lchristmann you are absolutely right, I am trying to solve it in wrong way. g00se has wrote the correct way how to do it. Thank you a lot, guys!

Answer (score 4):

fwiw, I just updated my timezone database using the tool [HERE](https://www.azul.com/products/components/ziupdater-time-zone-tool/) using [the IANA data](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2024a.tar.gz) and then ran the following code:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KzZones {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String zones = """
            Asia/Almaty
            Asia/Qyzylorda
            Asia/Qostanay
            Asia/Aqtobe
            Asia/Aqtau
            Asia/Atyrau
            Asia/Oral
        """;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(zones).useDelimiter("\\R");
        s.tokens().
            map(String::trim).
            map(ZoneId::of).
            forEach(z ->System.out.printf("Area: %s, rules: %s%n", z, z.getRules()));
    }
}
```

After the update, the run gave the following:

```
goose@nucsrv:/tmp$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
goose@nucsrv:/tmp$ java KzZones
Area: Asia/Almaty, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Qyzylorda, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Qostanay, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Aqtobe, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Aqtau, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Atyrau, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Oral, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
```

On a box with no update, I got:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ java -version
openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+14-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+14-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
goose@t410:/tmp$ java KzZones 
Area: Asia/Almaty, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+06:00]
Area: Asia/Qyzylorda, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Qostanay, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+06:00]
Area: Asia/Aqtobe, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Aqtau, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Atyrau, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
Area: Asia/Oral, rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=+05:00]
```

The first run is consistent with the [Wikipedia article on Kazahkstan timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Kazakhstan)

Comment: Nice. See also: [*Get the current version number of `tzdata`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40416090/642706). And, find the latest version of *tzdata* [at the IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Currently: 2024a (Released 2024-02-01).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that wouldn't do it for me as it's Oracle-specific. afaik the one I used is portable