# Egypt time zone java and joda libraries updated before DST 2023 does that need an update for 2024 DST

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, dst

We are having a system running on servers having EET time zone, In 2023 before DST changes in Egypt, Java (jre8) and Joda(2.12.5) libraries were updated and it worked fine with EEST time zone. this year2024 Egypt is again doing DST and changing time zone to EEST. Do we need to apply a new patch for java-8 and Joda libraries to make it work, or previous one should work as expected

Comment: It certainly won't hurt to update the timezone data with the latest from IANA. See the details in my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139615/change-timezone-offset-for-zoneid/78140584#78140584)

Comment: When your servers have been updated to apply summer time (DST) for Egypt (EEST), that update has effect for every year, so summer time in 2024 is no reason for needing to update again.

Comment: You can test that with a trivial Java program for example printing an appropriately formatted date and time in the summer time part of the year (after end of April): `LocalDate.of(2024, Month.MAY, 1) .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Africa/Cairo")) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL))` and similar for Joda-Time. The output should mention Eastern European *Summer* Time (on my computer it doesn’t, it seems I still need that update from last year). You may also try for 2025, 2026, ... in case.

Comment: Usage: EET, Eastern European Time, is not a time zone. It’s a common name and abbreviation used for many time zones from Europe/Helsinki to Africa/Egypt. EEST, Eastern European Summer Time, also is not a time zone but an abbreviation used for some of *the same* time zones during the part of year where summer time (DST) is in effect (if the time zone in question uses that).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

If the politicians have changed the rules for a time zone of interest to the stakeholders of your systems, then yes of course you must update all the *tzdata* files in all the places where they exist.

- If you care about `Africa/Cairo`, and the Egyptian politicians have changed the rules, then you *must* update all copies of *tzdata* everywhere.
- If the politicians of Ecuador change the rules for `Pacific/Galapagos`, but your stakeholders have no interest in [Galápagos Islands](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal%C3%A1pagos_Islands), then you can leave your existing *tzdata* files in place.

## Details

If the politicians have changed the rules of a time zone of interest to you, then of course you must update the [tzdata](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

A ***tzdata* file is simply text**, listing every time zone around the globe along with the rules listing the past, preset, and future changes to the offset from UTC used by the people of a particular region as decoded by their politicians. So no magic here. If the politicians have changed the rules, then your tzdata text file is invalid. You must replace each and every copy of the *tzdata* text file on your machines.

**Beware:** Politicians in different places have been unwisely making such changes with shockingly little forewarning.

Note that you likely have copies of tzdata in multiple places:

- **Java Virtual Machine** (JDK, JRE)
- **Libraries** such as [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- **Database engine** such as Postgres
- Host **operating system** (OS)

If updating one, update all.

If the politicians have made no changes to the time zones of interest to you, then no need to update tzdata.

But it certainly does not hurt to update tzdata. New versions arrive a few times a year, typically.

The tzdata is published by the [IANA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority). At [this page](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) you can
see the latest update. And there you can **sign up for email announcements** of new releases.

---

Beware: 2-4 letter pseudo-zones like EEST, IST, and CST are *not* actual time zones. These pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique! Use these only when localizing text for presentation to the user. Never use these in your technical discussions, logic, and data.

[Real time zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) have a name in format of `Continint/Region` such as `Africa/Cairo`, `Europe/Paris`, `Pacific/Auckland`.