# Java DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME Returns different values in Java 9+ compared to Java 8

Tags: java

When running the below code I get different behaviour with different versions of the JDK:

In **Java 8** I get:

```
2020-01-07T09:34:38.994Z
```

In **Java 11** I get:

```
2020-01-07T09:37:05.55126Z
```

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();

        DateTimeFormatter isoOffsetDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

        String format = isoOffsetDateTime.format(now);

        System.out.println(format);
    }
}
```

Running in https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ just to make it easier to swap JDKs quickly

Is this change documented anywhere as I couldn't find anything and/or does anyone know why it's happening ? I spotted this as the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is the default Jackson formatter for a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZonedDateTime change behavior jdk 8/11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255020/zoneddatetime-change-behavior-jdk-8-11)

Comment: @amer that seems to be a different problem (time zone related, while this is related to the precision of the fractional seconds)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok, my bad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour of the formatter hasn't changed, but the thing you're formatting has.

The precision of datetimes returned by `now()` methods increased. [JDK-8068730](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the old milliseconds format with Java 9+, you can truncate using temporal ChronoUnit for `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`. Example:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS).toString();
// OR
Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS).toString();
```

***NOTE***: In a very rare case, when `now()` executes at `000` milli-seconds of time, you will see above returns without `SSS` in the output i.e `2020-01-07T09:34:38Z` instead of `2020-01-07T09:34:38.000Z`.