# Storing appointments in a SQL database such as Postgres for use with java.time framework

Tags: java, database, postgresql, timezone, java-time

Let's say that we have an appointment in [Milan Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milan) happening on 01/23/2021 21:00 "Europe/Rome". This appointment is saved to the database in UTC in a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Now a user living in [New York US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City) needs to understand when this appointment will take place. We can show that user the date-time converted to "America/New_York" time zone, or instead, in "Europe/Rome" TZ. Once the user will fly from New York to Milan, he will find both info useful.

The point is to store everything converted into the same TZ reference (UTC), and the manipulate the date-time depending on the goal you have using the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) framework bundled with modern Java.

Makes sense or there is something wrong/missing?

Comment: 01/23/2021 21:00 may not be the best example for your point since it is only a few months away (though time zone rules have been observed to change with weeks’ notice or shorter). Had you said just 11/23/2021, I would no longer have been able to tell you the UTC offset for Italy (Milan) come that date.

Comment: @OleV.V. The point of my Answer is that you can never *know* the future offset used by any particular time zone, you can only *guess* based on current rules. Those rules are subject to change at any moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Makes sense or there is something wrong/missing?

It depends on the kind of appointment.

There are two kinds of appointments:

- A moment, a specific point on the timeline, ignoring any changes to time zone rules.
  Example: Rocket launch.
- A date and time-of-day that should adjust for changes to time zone rules.
  Example: Medical/Dental visit.

[image: Diagram summarizing two kinds of appointments, moment oriented versus time-of-day oriented, each using a different type in Java and SQL.]

## Moment

If we are booking the launch of a rocket, for example, we do not care about the date and the time-of-day. We only care about the moment when (a) the heavens align, and (b) we expect favorable weather.

If in the intervening time the politicians change the rules of the time zone in use at our launch site or at our offices, that has no effect on our launch appointment. If politicians governing our launch site adopt [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), the moment of our launch remains the same. If the politicians governing our offices decide to [change the clock a half-hour earlier because of diplomatic relations](https://news.sky.com/story/north-korea-resets-clocks-by-half-an-hour-to-match-south-11358551) with a neighboring country, the moment of our launch remains the same.

For such an appointment, yes, your approach would be correct. You would record the appointment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) using a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Upon retrieval, adjust into any time zone the user prefers.

Databases such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) use any time zone info accompanying an input to adjust into UTC, and then disposes of that time zone info. When you retrieve the value from Postgres, it will always represent a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC. Beware, some tooling or middleware may have the anti-feature of applying some default time zone between retrieval from database and delivery to you the programmer. But be clear: Postgres always saves and retrieves values of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in UTC, always UTC, and [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Here is some example Java code.

```
LocalDate launchDateAsSeenInRome = LocalDate.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 ) ;
LocalTime launchTimeAsSeenInRome = LocalTime.of( 21 , 0 ) ;
ZoneId zoneEuropeRome = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Rome" ) ;
// Assemble those three parts to determine a moment.
ZonedDateTime launchMomentAsSeenInRome = ZonedDateTime.of( launchDateAsSeenInRome , launchTimeAsSeenInRome , zoneEuropeRome ) ;
```

> launchMomentAsSeenInRome.toString(): 2021-01-23T21:00+01:00[Europe/Rome]

To see the same moment in UTC, convert to an `Instant`. An `Instant` object always represents a moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant launchInstant = launchMomentAsSeenInRome.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from Rome time zone to UTC.
```

> launchInstant.toString(): 2021-01-23T20:00:00Z

The `Z` on the end of the above string example is standard notation for UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

Unfortunately the JDBC 4.2 team neglected to require support for either [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) types. So your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) may or may not be able to read/write such objects to your database. If not, simply convert to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). All three types represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. But `OffsetDateTime` has support required by [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) [4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) for reasons that escape me.

```
OffsetDateTime odtLaunchAsSeenInRome = launchMomentAsSeenInRome.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Writing to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odtLaunchAsSeenInRome ) ;
```

Retrieval from database.

```
OffsetDateTime launchMoment = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust to the New York time zone desired by your user.

```
ZoneId zoneAmericaNewYork = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime launchAsSeenInNewYork = launchMoment.atZoneSameInstant( zoneAmericaNewYork ) ;
```

> launchAsSeenInNewYork.toString(): 2021-01-23T15:00-05:00[America/New_York]

You can see all of the above [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WHTBD9).

By the way, tracking past events are also treated as a moment. When did the patient actually arrive for appointment, when did the customer pay the invoice, when did a new hire sign their documents, when did the server crash… all these are tracked as a moment in UTC. As discussed above, usually that would be an `Instant`, though `ZonedDateTime` & `OffsetDateTime` also represent a moment. For the database use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (not `WITHOUT`).

## Time-of-day

I expect most business-oriented apps are focused on appointments of the other type, where we aim at a date with a time-of-day rather than a specific moment.

If the user makes an appointment with their health care provider to review the results of a test, they do so for a particular time-of-day on that date. If in the meantime the politicians change the rules of their time zone, moving the clock ahead or behind an hour or half-hour or any other amount of time, the date and time-of-day of that medical appointment remain the same. In actuality, the point of the timeline of the original appointment will be changed after the politicians change the time zone, shifting to an earlier/later point on the timeline.

For such appointmentss, we do *not* store the date and time-of-day as seen in UTC. We do *not* use the database column type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

For such appointments, we store the date with time-of-day without any regard to time zone. We use a database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (notice `WITHOUT` rather than `WITH`). The matching type in Java is `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDate medicalApptDate = LocalDate.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 ) ;
LocalTime medicalApptTime = LocalTime.of( 21 , 0 ) ;
LocalDateTime medicalApptDateTime = LocalDateTime.of( medicalApptDate , medicalApptTime ) ;
```

Write that to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , medicalApptDateTime ) ;
```

Be clear on this: a `LocalDateTime` object does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a specific point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` object represents a range of *possible* moments along about 26-27 hours of the timeline (the range of time zones around the globe). To give real meaning to a `LocalDateTime`, we must associate an intended time zone.

For that intended time zone, use a second column to store the zone identifier. For example, the strings `Europe/Rome` or `America/New_York`. See [list of zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```
ZoneId zoneEuropeRome = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Rome" ) ;
```

Write that to the database as text.

```
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , zoneEuropeRome ) ;
```

Retrieval. Retrieve the zone name as text, and instantiate a `ZoneId` object.

```
LocalDateTime medicalApptDateTime = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId medicalApptZone = ZoneId.of( myResultSet.getString( … ) ) ;
```

Put those two pieces together to determine a moment represented as a `ZonedDateTime` object. Do this dynamically when you need to schedule a calendar. But do *not* store the moment. If the politicians redefine the time zone(s) in the future, a different moment must be calculated then.

```
ZonedDateTime medicalApptAsSeenInCareProviderZone = ZonedDateTime.of( medicalApptDateTime , medicalApptZone ) ;
```

The user is traveling to New York US. They need to know when to call the health care provider in Milan Italy according to the clocks on the wall in their temporary location of New York. So adjust from one time zone to another. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId zoneAmericaNewYork = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime medicalApptAsSeenInNewYork = medicalApptAsSeenInCareProviderZone.withZoneSameInstant( zoneAmericaNewYork ) ;
```

---

## *tzdata*

Be aware that if the rules of your desired time zones may be changing, you must update the copy of time zone definitions on your computers.

Java contains its own copy of the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), as does the Postgres database engine. And your host operating system as well. This particular code shown here requires only Java to be up-to-date. If you use Postgres to make time zone adjustments, its *tzdata* must also be up-to-date. And for logging and such, your host OS should be kept up-to-date. For proper clock-watching by the user, their client machine's OS must also be up-to-date.

Beware: Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for changing their time zones with surprising frequency, and often with little forewarning.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Welcome back! I am sure both, the question and the answer are going to get many likes. It will also encourage contributors to post quality questions and [answer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Basil thank you very much for this detailed explanation! I'll read it carefully in the next days in order to understand all the exposed concepts. The documentation in `java.time`, it's full of good information to read. I think that now I see your point, but regarding the time-of-day example, are you sure that the event moves on the timeline? Just think about a past event, if suddenly politicians change the TZ, that event still happened in the same moment on the timeline, we just refer to it in another way, by adjusting the offset. So isn't saving the offset a better option?

Comment: Just a little add: consider that the application will always refer to events happening in the same country, so we can assume that the Timezone will always be the same. In this case the user in NYC will receive the time from the server in UTC, and an hypothetical frontend will take that UTC time and convert in: NYC time (customer will know a good moment to call the health care provider) and Rome time, to know when to present himself at the center once he arrives in Rome.

Comment: @funder7 When you want to track when an event actually happened, past-tense, then always represent as a moment in UTC. Usually that would be an `Instant`, though `ZonedDateTime` & `OffsetDateTime` also represent a moment. For the database use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `WITHOUT`. For example: When did the patient actually arrive for appointment, when did the customer pay the invoice, when did a new hire sign their documents, when did the server crash… all these are tracked as a moment in UTC. I added this to the Answer.

Comment: Consider that I generated this project with jhipster, which uses liquibase. I did a quick test, by creating a simple entity with one field for each date type (`Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDateTime`). It's curious because they're all mapped to a `datetime` column which in turn is stored as a `timestamp` on the db. On liquibase you define the structure of the db, once that is done you can generate an h2, mysql, postgres, etc. So datetime is the liquibase internal definition. I was expecting to have the timezone saved with `ZonedDateTime`, but apparently is not.

Comment: If -all- datetime columns are represented in UTC format, wouldn't be redundant to define them with timezone? I mean, they will all end with +00. Maybe it's better to keep the timezone, even if it's UTC, in case we need to send this time information to an external system?

Comment: @funder7 The premise of your last comment is incorrect. **Not all database columns store UTC.** The `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type has *no* regard for time zone. It stores only a date with a time-of-day. No default time zone is applied. If you specify an input carrying time zone or offset info, that info is ignored, with only the date and time being saved as-is, no adjustment. Easy enough for you to try for yourself. Just be careful about middleware or tooling lying to you about retrieved values, where they inject a time zone adjustment. This may include the *pgAdmin* tool.

Comment: Okay. I mean that the timezone is implicit on the db. So even if it's not specified, we can assume that every datetime is in UTC. There's a property that you can set on hibernate where you set the db timezone (UTC). It takes care of converting every datetime in input to utc. Then you can keep it in UTC on presentation layer, or convert to any timezone you like. Anyway I'm following your suggestion by using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`, it's better to be explicit about what data is stored :-)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to leave the conversion to PostgreSQL. If you set the `timezone` parameter correctly for each session and use `timestamp with time zone` PostgreSQL will automatically show the timestamp to the New York user in New York time.