# Why does LocalDateTime.ofInstant() requires ZoneId

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, localdatetime, java.time.instant

In Java,

- If `Instant` represents a point in time, encoded as date and time in
  UTC.
- And `LocalDateTime` represents a point in time, encoded as date and time in the JVM local timezone.

Why then does `LocalDateTime.ofInstant()` require a `ZoneId` as a second argument ?

This makes `LocalDateTime` not only confusing and potentially incorrect, but also makes it identical to `ZonedDateTime`; because the timezone of `LocalDateTime` can be any timezone just like `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: There really isn’t much good use for `LocalDateTime`. I think I have always preferred `ZonedDateTime` because it makes time zone explicit, contrary to `LocalDateTime`. For one case where you *do* need a `LocalDateTime` see [Storing appointments in a SQL database such as Postgres for use with java.time framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545555/storing-appointments-in-a-sql-database-such-as-postgres-for-use-with-java-time-f).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> And `LocalDateTime` represents a point in time, encoded as date and time in the JVM local timezone.

No, that's not true. Regardless of the "encoded as" part (which I highly doubt, but which I don't have significant knowledge of to disprove), a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a point in time. It represents a local date/time, without reference to a specific time zone. Any given `LocalDateTime` occurs at different points in time in different time zones.

Currently the local date and time in the Europe/London time zone is 2023-01-26T08:50. The *same point in time* in (say) America/New_York would result in a different `LocalDateTime`. Whereas in America/New_York, the `LocalDateTime` of 2023-01-26T08:50 occurs as a different point in time.

For some `LocalDateTime` / time zone combinations, there may be zero or two corresponding points in time - for example, the `LocalDateTime` 2022-11-06T01:30 will occur in America/New_York at both 2022-11-06 05:30:00Z and 2022-11-06 06:30:00Z.

Hopefully this is sufficient evidence that a `LocalDateTime` really *isn't* a point in time...

Comment: One may add that the JVM default time zone can be changed on runtime, which would under the OP’s interpretation have caused the `LocalDateTime` object to refer to a different point in time. Of course this is not the intended interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

A LocalDateTime represents a date and time without time zone information. It is used to represent "local time" (as an example for me, right now the local time is 2023-01-26 09:50). An Instant is always at UTC (example, the time right now is 2023-01-26 08:50 UTC). To transform between an Instant and what the observer considers to be local time, you need to know the ZoneId of the location of the observer (e.g. for me Europe/Amsterdam), otherwise you cannot derive a local time.

And to be clear, a LocalDateTime does not represent a point in time (that is what Instant is for). To expand my example, for me the local time 2023-01-26 09:50 is now past, while for Jon Skeet (in Europe/London), that local time will happen in slightly less than an hour).

Answer (score 1):

`.ofInstant()` is there to specify the instant and timezone.

If you don't want to specify the time zone and instant  you can use `.now()` wich will use the local date and time.

If you want to specify the instant but not the ZoneId you can use `ZomeId.systemDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

An `Instant` is independent from time zones or offsets, but a `LocalDateTime` is not. Although it does not have a `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset`, it's values are partially based on the offset the specific zone currently has.

Here's a code example with different zones that lead to different values of the very same `Instant`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DateTimeParseException {
    // example instant (see output)
    var instant = Instant.now();
    // get the instant with different time zones
    var ldtBerlin = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
    var ldtCanberra = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Australia/Canberra"));
    var ldtKolkata = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    var ldtLA = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    // print all the results
    System.out.println("Instant " + instant.toEpochMilli() + " in different zones:");
    System.out.println(ldtBerlin + " (Berlin)");
    System.out.println(ldtCanberra + " (Canberra)");
    System.out.println(ldtKolkata + " (Kolkata)");
    System.out.println(ldtLA + " (Los Angeles)");
}
```

Output:

```
Instant 1674724841016 in different zones:
2023-01-26T10:20:41.016228 (Berlin)
2023-01-26T20:20:41.016228 (Canberra)
2023-01-26T14:50:41.016228 (Kolkata)
2023-01-26T01:20:41.016228 (Los Angeles)
```

View the different values, those are the local dates and times of the zones, but a `LocalDateTime` does not have any! You can use other objects, like `ZonedDateTime` (has zone and offset) and `OffsetDateTime` (has offset). Both of them have a method `toLocalDateTime()`, in case you need a `LocalDateTime` later on…