# Java Time Zone Database vs IANA data

Tags: java, timezone, dst

There is a Daylight Savings Time discrepancy between the IANA database and the Java tzdb.dat 2019c 
database in the Africa/Cassablanca time zone that has me very confused.  There may be others but I found this one.  From what I can tell the IANA time zone database clearly shows that DST is supported in Morocco (Africa/Casablanca) unfortunately the Java time zone database tzdb.dat in the 2019c release does not agree. This has and will cause me infinite grief.  What am I missing here,  or have others seen this kind of thing

The IANA table 2019c for Africa/Casablanca

**Note: the part of the table below shows that the normal time is UTC+1 and Day light savings time is UTC a slash (/) separates standard and daylight abbreviations**

## Zone  NAME        STDOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]

Zone Africa/Casablanca  -0:30:20 -  LMT 1913 Oct 26

```
         0:00   Morocco +00/+01 1984 Mar 16
         1:00   -   +01 1986
         0:00   Morocco +00/+01 2018 Oct 28  3:00    
         1:00   Morocco +01/+00
```

From Oct 28 2018 till present offset is +1 for standard and +0 for daylight savings  (a slash (/) separates standard and daylight abbreviations.)
STDOFF 1:00 so The amount of time to add to UT to get standard time, without any adjustment for daylight saving this corresponds to UTC +1 that is the current Morocco time. 
So we take Zone Africa/Casablanca which is UTC and add the offsets +01/+00 depending on Ramadan.'

The test

I wrote a simple Java class to check the 2019c TZDB. This class (shown below) shows that something is wrong with the latest Java time zone data file  tzdb.dat file.  This test was run using IBM SR5FP40 with the time zone 2019c data file. I had the same results with OpenJDK using a 2019c datafile.

First line from tzdb.dat shows 2019c
 TZDB  2019cX Africa/Abidjan Africa/Accra Africa/Addis_Ababa Africa/Algiers

Test that shows the problem

Time Zone = Africa/Casablanca
Supports Day light Savings time  = false
Date Mon May 20 00:00:00 WET 2019 is currently in DST false
Time zone name Western European Time
Time zone ID Africa/Casablanca

A baseline test was also run to show if DST is supported the code will show it.

Time Zone = Europe/Rome
Supports Day light Savings time  = true
Date Mon May 20 00:00:00 CEST 2019 is currently in DST true
Time zone name Central European Time
Time zone ID Europe/Rome

The code is here for reference

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class checkdaylight{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        // Create TimeZone object
        //Europe/Rome
        //Pacific/Pago_Pago
        //Africa/Casablanca
        String TimezoneToTest = "Africa/Casablanca";
        System.out.println("Time Zone = " + TimezoneToTest);
        TimeZone obj = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimezoneToTest); 
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimezoneToTest)); //to avoid confusion

        // Checking day light time 
        // and displaying the result 
        System.out.println("Supports Day light Savings time  = "
                        + obj.useDaylightTime()); 
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        try{
            simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimezoneToTest));
            Date checkdate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2019-05-20");
            System.out.println("Date " + checkdate.toString()+ " is currently in DST "+ obj.inDaylightTime(checkdate));
         } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Time zone name " +obj.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println("Time zone ID " + obj.getID());

    } 
}
```

Comment: Not answering your question, I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone` `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 11):

## Morocco now on DST permanently

As of October 26, 2018, **Morocco switched to [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) permanently<sup>†</sup>**.

The [Morocco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morocco) government gave only 2 days notice(!), in [*Decree 2.18.855*](https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2018/10/256091/time-change-morocco-daylight-saving/).  Apparently the government intends to stop all clock-shifting, with no more changes for [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) nor for [Ramadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan). This decree means an **offset of `+01:00` year-round**.

This decree also means Morocco is no longer “on DST”. The new-normal is an offset one hour ahead of UTC, whereas in the old days the offset was normally at UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). So notice in the code below that calling [`ZoneRules::isDaylightSavings`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings(java.time.Instant)) returns *false* nowadays (early 2020).

See Wikipedia for details: [*Daylight saving time in Morocco*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Morocco).

<sup>†</sup>When I say “permanently”, take that with a [grain of salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_of_salt). Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for frequently changing the offset of their respective time zone(s). This "permanently on DST" is only the latest fad to have caught the fancy of politicians. Always expect further changes.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. There is no longer any reason to use those awful legacy classes.

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## *java.time*

Specify your intended time zone.

```
ZoneId zCasablanca = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
```

Fetch the zone rules.

```
ZoneRules rulesCasablanca = zCasablanca.getRules() ;
```

Interrogate the rules that apply for a specific moment in that zone.

```
ZoneOffset offset = rulesCasablanca.getOffset( Instant.now() ) ;
boolean isDst = rules.isDaylightSavings( instant ) ;
```

Or collapse that to a single line.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ).getRules().getOffset( Instant.now() ) ;
```

Verify your version of Java.

```
System.out.println( "Java vendor and version:" ) ;
System.out.println( "    " + System.getProperty("java.vendor") ) ;
System.out.println( "    " + Runtime.version() ) ;

String tzdataVersion = 
    java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider
              .getVersions("UTC")
              .lastEntry()
              .getKey() 
;
System.out.println( "tzdata: " + tzdataVersion ) ;
System.out.println( "" ) ;
```

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/roGeYW).

> Java vendor and version:
>
> Oracle Corporation
>
> 12.0.1+12
>
> tzdata: 2018g
>
> offset.toString(): +01:00
>
> isDst: false

### Specific date

Let's try your specific date.

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2019-05-20" ) ;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
    System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt ) ;
    System.out.println(
        "offset: " + rules.getOffset( zdt.toInstant() ) + 
        "  |  is in DST: " + rules.isDaylightSavings( zdt.toInstant() ) 
    );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-05-20T00:00+01:00[Africa/Casablanca]
>
> offset: +01:00  |  is in DST: false

## *tzdata*

Oracle [lists](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) files built into Java runtimes.

That list shows that the Morocco switch to permanent DST was accounted for in `tzdata2018g`. That tzdata file was bundled with Java versions 11.0.2, 8u201, and 7u211. At least Oracle bundled it, while I assume the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project did so as well (I did not verify).

> Morocco switches to permanent +01 on 2018-10-27.
>
> Morocco switches from +00/+01 to permanent +01 effective 2018-10-27, so its clocks will not fall back on 2018-10-28 as previously scheduled.

To get the version of the tzdata data file in use by your JVM, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775223/642706) on the Question, [*Java - find tzdata version in use regardless of JRE version*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7956044/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the new classes and I did try them unfortunately they agree with the old ones and  the confusion still exists. My confusion comes from the fact that the IANA table for 2019c disagrees with the comments above.  Is it possible the Ramadon dates and associated fall back calculations are ignored (have a look at Africa in the IANA data) the data won't fit here.
Please see comments from: 
Naoufal Semlali (2019-04-16) and Paul Eggert (2019-05-20):

Comment: Running further tests shows new calls show DST normally and not DST during Ramadan