# Historic timezone offsets in newer JDK versions

Tags: java, java-11, timezone-offset, tzdata

I found a weird java discrepancy while testing some timezones with the use of `ZonedDateTime`. I was trying to parse a date before 1970 and saw that the result changes between java versions. The offset for Netherlands in 1932 is `+00:19`. Does anyone know why this happens? I feel this might be related with the bundling of european timezones in the time zone database project (https://github.com/eggert/tz), but i'm not sure. Is there a way to get the old behavior in java? Like with a setting?

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse("1932-10-20T10:19:32.000").atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
System.out.println(zdt);
    
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendFraction(NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, true)
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "Z")
    .toFormatter();

System.out.println(formatter.format(zdt));

System.out.println(
    java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider
                  .getVersions("UTC")
                  .lastEntry()
                  .getKey()
);
```

Result in Temurin (java jdk) 11.0.16 (expected output), last line showing timezone database version:

```
1932-10-20T10:19:32+00:19:32[Europe/Amsterdam]
1932-10-20T10:19:32.000+00:19
2022a
```

Result in Temurin 11.0.17:

```
1932-10-20T10:19:32Z[Europe/Amsterdam]
1932-10-20T10:19:32.000Z
2022c
```

**Edit**: Also an issue in JDK 17 starting from 17.0.5:

Temurin 17.0.4:

```
1932-10-20T10:19:32+00:19:32[Europe/Amsterdam]
1932-10-20T10:19:32.000+00:19
2022a
```

Temurin 17.0.5:

```
1932-10-20T10:19:32Z[Europe/Amsterdam]
1932-10-20T10:19:32.000Z
2022c
```

Comment: On OpenJDK 17, I get the expected output.

Comment: @Sweeper Which exact version? This might very well have to do with timezone DB changes, which can vary by point release (e.g. I have the "wrong" output with Temurin 17.0.6.10).

Comment: Timezone database versions per JDK version: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/tzdata-versions.html

Comment: @OleV.V. The thing here though is that a *newer* version of the JDK, and the timezone database are giving different behaviour.

Comment: I checked a few versions of the tzdb and found that the amsterdam zone got moved from the europe file to the backzone file. Other than that, I couldn't find any significant changes on the versions I checked (all 2020a+). It might be helpful if you can [specify what version of tzdb you are using.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775223/5133585)

Comment: @Sweeper, I've edited the question with extra information regarding timezone database versions.

Comment: Okay, I found it. It is [this line in this commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/0b925f6d8aaf927ac20049ae0ff3b527684b60c7#diff-b11f203e8e6ce90d0ab5a01a37ac248669987afb2a50fe0224fa8b8c5c985a73R964). They basically made Amsterdam an alias of Brussels because they share the same times post-1970. 2022b was the first version this change was applied to, it seems.

Comment: @Sweeper We (I'm a colleague of Bastiaan) suspected that that change might be relevant, but I figured that the move of that data to `backzone` was just administrative; not that it would actually change behaviour downstream! It seems like rather an impactful thing if it is.

Comment: I've found a related issue thread for the Corretto JDK here: https://github.com/corretto/corretto-17/issues/100

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm a colleague of OP. This issue has half the office baffled.*

Helped along by comments by @Sweeper below the question, I think we've found the cause.

## Background

The venerable Timezone Database [did some housecleaning](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/0b925f6d8aaf927ac20049ae0ff3b527684b60c7#diff-b11f203e8e6ce90d0ab5a01a37ac248669987afb2a50fe0224fa8b8c5c985a73R964) in 2022, and archived a lot of pre-1970 timezone data in their `backzone` file for version `2022b`. This allowed them to merge, for example, `Europe/Brussels` and `Europe/Amsterdam` in the leaner post-1970 database (because after 1970, these are in fact equal).

They also introduced a special option (`PACKRATLIST`) for building the timezone database **with** the historic timezones intact.

OpenJDK updated to the new version of the Timezone Database, but chose to use the version without historical data, and subsequently, [some developers noticed things breaking](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-17/issues/100).

[The relevant OpenJDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8292223) however currently lists supporting the `backzone` as **won't fix**.

## Affected JDK's

- Java 11 from 11.0.17 onwards.
- Java 17 from 17.0.5 onwards.

## Possible solutions

- Perhaps newer JDK's will fix this after all? [Unknown at this moment.](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8303899)
- Alternatively, use the newer JDK's, but apply [this workaround](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-17/issues/100#issuecomment-1287485126) to install an older version (`2022a`) of the Timezone Database instead.
- Or, rewrite all code that depends on this historical data, possibly by hardcoding the relevant timezone offsets if it is a limited set.

Comment: Thanks. You may want to spell out the workaround from Coretto in the answer itself since this seems to be short-term safest and least hacky solution and since I am not sure whether the comment on the Corretto issue  will stay for the lifetime of Stack Overflow.