# TzdbZoneRulesProvider not working in java.time

Tags: kotlin, java-time, threetenbp

I'm migrating an old code base away from the `threeten` backport library to use `java.time` instead. There is a test method that no longer works, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the class *before* the changes. This compiles correctly:

```
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId
import org.threeten.bp.zone.TzdbZoneRulesProvider
import org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider

open class BaseAvailabilityTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    open fun setUp() {
        if (ZoneRulesProvider.getAvailableZoneIds().isEmpty()) {
            val stream = this.javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream("TZDB.dat")
            stream.use(::TzdbZoneRulesProvider).apply {
                ZoneRulesProvider.registerProvider(this)
            }
        }
        zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")
    }
}
```

But when I switch the `threeten` imports over to `java.time` like this:

```
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.zone.TzdbZoneRulesProvider
import java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider
```

then Android Studio shows an error:

```
Type mismatch
Required: (TypeVariable(T))->TypeVariable(R)
Found: KFunction0<TzdbZoneRulesProvider>
```

I can't find anything that addresses this issue. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to register the tzdb provider explicitly. That is the default provider for the JVM, as documented in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesProvider.html).

> The Java virtual machine has a default provider that provides zone rules for the time-zones defined by IANA Time Zone Database (TZDB). If the system property java.time.zone.DefaultZoneRulesProvider is defined then it is taken to be the fully-qualified name of a concrete ZoneRulesProvider class to be loaded as the default provider, using the system class loader. If this system property is not defined, a system-default provider will be loaded to serve as the default provider.

In fact, [`TzdbZoneRulesProvider`](https://code.yawk.at/java/17/java.base/java/time/zone/TzdbZoneRulesProvider.java) is a package-private class in `java.time.zone`, so you cannot access it anyway.

This essentially means that you can remove this `if` entirely:

```
if (ZoneRulesProvider.getAvailableZoneIds().isEmpty()) {
    val stream = this.javaClass.classLoader?.getResourceAsStream("TZDB.dat")
    stream.use(::TzdbZoneRulesProvider).apply {
        ZoneRulesProvider.registerProvider(this)
    }
}
```

If your tests depend on a particular version of tzdb (like in very rare situations such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75359690/5133585)), you can use the [timezone updater tool](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/tzupdater-readme.html) to change the tzdb version in your JDK. An example is described [here](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-17/issues/100#issuecomment-1287485126).