# After migrating to Java 17, the date is displayed inaccurately

Tags: java, mongodb, timezone, java-17, java.util.date

We've recently transitioned our application from Java 11 to Java 17. Subsequent to the deployment, we've noticed that certain records exhibit a discrepancy where dates are displaying with a one-day difference (+1). This occurs specifically in records with years before 1940. Our application operates in the CEST timezone, and dates are stored in MongoDB as UTC. The following examples highlight instances where we've identified the issue.

| DB | Java 11 | Java 17 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1934-07-21T22:40:28.000+00:00 | 1934-07-22 | 1934-07-21 |
| 1897-08-06T23:40:28.000+00:00 | 1897-08-07 | 1897-08-06 |

The provided code snippet, written in Kotlin, produces satisfactory results in Java 11. However, when executed with Java 17, the same code fails to function as expected.

```kotlin
fun main() {  // Kotlin code
    val date = Date(-1118625572000) //1934-07-21T22:40:28.000+00:00
    println("Date: ${date.toInstant()?.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"))!!.toLocalDate()}")
}
```

**Java11 Output:**
[image: Code output showing "Date: 1934-07-22"]

**Java17 Output:**
[image: Code output showing "Date: 1934-07-21"]

Is there a solution available in Java 17 to address issues related to these types of dates?

We attempted to rectify those records directly in the database to ensure the population of valid dates.

For example,

```
1934-07-21T22:40:28.000+00:00 --> 1934-07-22T00:00:00.000+00:00
1897-08-06T23:40:28.000+00:00 --> 1897-08-07T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

However, we need to explore whether there is a way to handle these types of dates specifically in Java 17.

Comment: What timezone are you in? The chances are that a Java version after 11 introduced some fixes to the timezone database it uses?

Comment: Date and time handling in general is a minefield, and without seeing the actual code used I think any answer will be mostly conjecture. A [MCVE] would really help here.

Comment: @TurePålsson Added the minimal reproducible example. Kindly reopen.

Comment: Taking a look at [the historic daylight savings changes for CET specifcally](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/paris) it looks like there was indeed a change to the CET/CEST timezone in 1940 where CET transitioned from UTC to UTC+1 (CEST also transitioned - from UTC+1 to UTC+2).

Comment: Sure @phuzi. with that can you please re-open the question

Comment: Taking a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time) seems to indicate that CET didn't change, just that a couple of European countries adopted it which were previously using UTC/GMT. It seems that your application might be sensitive to this change. In particular The Netherlands went from UTC+00:20 to CET (UTC+1)!

Comment: Yes it's sensitive because the impact is on date of birth. Also this is I've not seen anywhere in any Java 17 migration blogs.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359690/historic-timezone-offsets-in-newer-jdk-versions

Comment: Converting between UTC and local time for dates as far back as 1897 seems *extremely* risky, especially if you risk falling over the midnight line to the wrong date if DST rule interpretations change (which would be my first guess as to what has happened here).

Comment: @TurePålsson The problem wasn't that the DST rule interpretations changed. It seems to be caused later Java versions shipping with a purposely broken/incomplete timezone database where The Netherlands has been lumped in with Brussels.

Comment: What is the result of `ZoneId.systemDefault()` in each of the cases you ran?

Comment: @phuzi The time changes you linked for 1934 were in April & October, so that has nothing to do with a date change in July.

Comment: @VivekBuddhadev No, your example is *not* reproducible. You call `ZoneId.systemDefault()` which is a wild card. We have no idea to know what that call returned in each of your runs. Replace that code with an explicit specific time zone, and re-run your code.

Comment: @BasilBourque: You can change to ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"). I've kept it as my server and system both have this timezone as default.

Comment: @VivekBuddhadev Your "server and system" defaults are irrelevant. The only default that matters here is the JVM’s current default time zone. And, that default can be changed at any moment by any code running in any thread of any app within that JVM. The only way to responsibly run your test is to specify a time zone rather than rely on a default.

Comment: @BasilBourque: I've specified the timezone in the example. Hope you'll able to reproduce the same

Comment: @VivekBuddhadev Run this: `Instant.ofEpochMilli( -1_118_625_572_000L ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Amsterdam" ) ).toString()` in each of your scenarios. I predict you will see the same text in each case: `1934-07-22T00:00+01:19:32[Europe/Amsterdam]` as seen [in Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/fZJsEq). As I explained in my Answer, your time-of-day is near the end of the day. When you ran some cases with a different time zone, even a different European time zone, that would be enough to bump (or not bump) from the 21st to the 22nd of July.

Comment: You're not the first Java developer to run across this Amsterdam time zone issue: [JDK-8303899](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8303899)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is due to the difference in [time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) being used in the two versions of Java.  Time zone rules are updated over time, and you've encountered an old date that is treated differently under newer rules.

For the versions of Java on my machine, I'm getting 1934-07-22 for Java 11 & 17 (time zone database versions 2020d & 2021e, respectively), but 1934-07-21 for Java 21 (time zone database version 2023c).

The specific reason for this is that 2020d & 2021e have a zone offset of +01:19:32 for this instant in Europe/Amsterdam.  On the other hand, 2023c has a zone offset of +01:00 in Europe/Amsterdam.  Adding 1:19:32 to 1934-07-21T22:40:28Z results in midnight the next day (1934-07-22), but adding 1:00:00 results in 23:40:28 the same day (1934-07-21).

## Time zone database change

I did some Internet sleuthing, and per the [time zone database mailing list](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-September/031904.html), it looks like this change was made in time zone database version 2022b.  So 2022a and earlier use the +01:19:32 offset, and 2022b and later use the +01:00 offset.

2022b merged the Amsterdam & Brussels time zones, which are identical after 1970, but differ in sufficiently early historical dates.  It looks like Amsterdam at one point used [local mean time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time), hence the strange-looking offset.  However, it seems that Brussels did not.

> > Between 2022a an b the timezone info for Europe/Amstedam is removed:
> >       Z Europe/Amsterdam 0:19:32 - LMT 1835
> > The timezone info for Brussels around that date differs from Amsterdams timezone info.
> >
> > Determining the timezone information for dates around that period on my Linux system in python returns since the latest update an offset of 0 minutes as opposed to the 19 minutes previously.
> >
> > Is the removal for this timezone information intentional or a bug?
>
> The maintainer has merged the Amsterdam and Brussels timezone information by using the Brussels rules for Amsterdam, as the rules don't differ since 1970, in the default data package. This wipes out Amsterdam rules from before 1970, including local mean time.

## Demonstration

```java
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.vendor") + Runtime.version();
String timeZoneDatabase = ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions("UTC")
        .keySet().stream().findFirst().orElseThrow();
Date date = new Date(-1118625572000L);
ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.toInstant().atZone(timeZone);
LocalDate localDate = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate();

System.out.printf("Java: %s%n", javaVersion);
System.out.printf("Time Zone Database: %s%n", timeZoneDatabase);
System.out.printf("Instant (UTC): %s%n", date.toInstant());
System.out.printf("LocalDate (Europe/Amsterdam): %s%n", localDate);
System.out.printf("Time zone offset: %s%n", zonedDateTime.getOffset());
```

### Output

```
Java: AdoptOpenJDK11.0.10+9
Time Zone Database: 2020d
Instant (UTC): 1934-07-21T22:40:28Z
LocalDate (Europe/Amsterdam): 1934-07-22
Time zone offset: +01:19:32
```

```
Java: Eclipse Adoptium17.0.2+8
Time Zone Database: 2021e
Instant (UTC): 1934-07-21T22:40:28Z
LocalDate (Europe/Amsterdam): 1934-07-22
Time zone offset: +01:19:32
```

```
Java: Eclipse Adoptium21.0.1+12-LTS
Time Zone Database: 2023c
Instant (UTC): 1934-07-21T22:40:28Z
LocalDate (Europe/Amsterdam): 1934-07-21
Time zone offset: +01:00
```

Comment: Amazing !!  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_Netherlands) has the history of timezone changes in Netherlands. At one point, they changed it to UTC+00:20

Answer (score -1):

### tl;dr

Your issue of differing dates likely has nothing to do with MongoDB, and nothing to do with versions of Java. Your issue is probably due to using different time zones.

The same moment has different dates when seen through different time zones.

Your code:

```kotlin
println("Date: ${date.toInstant()?.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())!!.toLocalDate()}")
```

… uses default time zone. I suspect that default varied at runtime.

Do not do that, **do not rely upon such defaults**.   Specify your expected/desired time zone explicitly. For example:

```java
Instant.ofEpochMilli( x ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ).toLocalDate()
```

### Details

> We've recently transitioned our application from Java 11 to Java 17.

Time zone rules change quite often. Most every version and update of Java includes a fresh [tzdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

> Subsequent to the deployment, we've noticed that certain records exhibit a discrepancy where dates are displaying with a one-day difference (+1).

Sounds like a time zone issue.

> This occurs specifically in records with years before 1940.

By the way… The time zone rules were retroactively documented mainly for 1970 and later. And even then the rules have some holes and inaccuracies. Going further back in decades is even more likely to be less accurate. Fixes are always possible in later versions of [tzdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

> Our application operates in the CEST timezone

No such thing as `CEST` time zone.

Text such as `CEST` is a pseudo-zone that gives a hint about what might be the intended time zone, and whether [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is in effect. Pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique(!). Never use these pseudo-zones for storing, exchanging, or processing date-time values. Use pseudo-zones only for presentation to the user.

Real time zones have a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris`, `America/Edmonton`, and `Pacific/Auckland`.

> dates are stored in MongoDB as UTC.

Exactly what data type did you use? Not covered in your Question.

> The provided code snippet, written in Kotlin, produces satisfactory results in Java 11. However, when executed with Java 17, the same code fails to function as expected.

The most likely explanation is that your issue (differing dates) has nothing to do with versions of Java… the issue involves a change in your JVMs’ current default time zone.

For any given moment,  **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. The same moment can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Los Angeles US.

Run this to verify the current default time zone (in Java syntax):

```java
System.out.println( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
```

Depending on such defaults is a great way to mess up your tests. Instead, specify your expected/desired time zone.

```java
System.out.println( Runtime.version() ) ;

Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( -1_118_625_572_000L ) ;  // Always has an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

ZoneId zLosAngeles = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;

ZonedDateTime zdtLosAngeles = instant.atZone( zLosAngeles ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = instant.atZone( zTokyo ) ;

System.out.println( "Same moment, different dates." );
System.out.println( zdtLosAngeles ) ;
System.out.println( zdtTokyo ) ;
```

See this code run at [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/TlHv1v). Notice the differing dates in effect for the same simultaneous point on the timeline. Alice in LA looks up to her wall calendar to see the 21st, while at the very same moment Bob in Tokyo looks up to his wall clock/calendar to see the 22nd.

> 12.0.1+12
>
> Same moment, different dates.
>
> 1934-07-21T14:40:28-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
>
> 1934-07-22T07:40:28+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

### Verify inputs

Let's run your examples through Java 12 [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/1u6My8).

```java
System.out.println( Runtime.version() ) ;

String v1934_input = "1934-07-21T22:40:28.000+00:00" ;
String v1897_input = "1897-08-06T23:40:28.000+00:00" ; 

Instant v1934_instant = Instant.parse ( v1934_input ) ;
Instant v1897_instant = Instant.parse ( v1897_input ) ;

long v1934_millis = v1934_instant.toEpochMilli() ;
long v1897_millis = v1897_instant.toEpochMilli() ;

System.out.println( v1934_input + " = " + v1934_instant + " = " + v1934_millis ) ;
System.out.println( v1897_input + " = " + v1897_instant + " = " + v1897_millis ) ;
```

> 12.0.1+12
>
> 1934-07-21T22:40:28.000+00:00 = 1934-07-21T22:40:28Z = -1118625572000
>
> 1897-08-06T23:40:28.000+00:00 = 1897-08-06T23:40:28Z = -2284762772000